# winternl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, mingw, reverse-engineering, mingw-w64

I'm using vscode and mingw to do a small project in C lang.

I wanted to use some NT functions, so I followed microsoft docs and used the "**winternl.h**" header file.

Here are my includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
```

But I get:

*winternl.h: No such file or directory*

This header is pretty basic, how mingw doesn't support it?

Thanks.

Comment: **mingw-w64** has that header file, see [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-headers/include/winternl.h). The include directories may not be configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `winternl.h` header is in a non-standard import location. If you're using visual studio, you have to add an additional include directory.

1. Open the property page for your code (`ALT +ENTER`)
2. Navigate to the C/C++ pane (under Configuration Properties)
3. Add the correct include directory for your system. For me, that's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\km`

It should be noted that the Windows docs do not in fact recommend linking against `winternl.h` - it's internal to Windows, and can change at any moment. If you need a function listed there, it's preferable to use run time dynamic linking, as the location of the function/structures you're using can change arbitrarily.